# OSX: Unable to open mysql workbench main window after closing it

Tags: macos, mysql-workbench

I have a problem with re-opening the main window of MySQL Workbench after I close it.

When I close the application (using the red close button on the top left corner of the MySQL Workbench window), the "main window" disappears.

[image: close main window]

The App Icon in the Dock shows that the application is still active.

[image: App is still active]

When I want to re-open MySQL Workbench, I press again on the Dock icon. However, the "main window" does not open again. The only way to get this window again is to really QUIT MySQL Workbench (Right click on Dock icon, then choose Quit), and then to re-open it.

How can I re-open the main window without having to really close the application time after time? Do I something wrong? Or is this a bug?

I have version mysql-workbench-community-8.0.13-macos-x86_64.
I am using MacOs Mojave version 10.14.2.

I noticed that sometimes I can reopen the main window using the top bar menu `View` -> `Home`, but a lot of the times this does not work either!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top-left red button doesn't mean "Quitting", only closing the window (some application automatically quit after closing, but some don't)

To make the Main Workbench window appear again, you can select the Menu "View" --> "Home". Then you should see a tab on top of that window, where you can click to go back to your view.

(So you don't need to quit, and open the application again)

Comment: Ok, so after closing the main window I can only re-open it by going in the menu in the top? I agree this works, but this is just not logical, right?

Comment: It can look surprising.  An application open and with no front window - only a top menu - is a bit weird (and useless). But it's the same behavior with "Preview" for example, or Page, or Word, or TextEdit, and many others: after you close the document you're working with, the application doesn't quit, and only have its top-menu left.